# How to check for errors in Ruby as IntelliJ does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

Recently I had a problem with a Rails application with the following code:

```rb
class MyBaseController < ApplicationController
  def error(a, b)
    # ...
  end
end

class MyController < MyBaseController
  def my_action
    begin
      another_method
    rescue e
      # The next line had a typo, it should
      # have been "e" instead of "error" and
      # hence it caused and unhandled exception
      logger.error("the error was #{error}")

      # ...
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

As you can see the logging statement will fail as it will try to call the `error` method from `MyBaseController` instead of getting the value of `e`.

This was an honest mistake but from what I see it could have been prevented: when I opened my application in IntelliJ with the Ruby plugin it marked the error with a red *squiggle*. Is not the first time I've seen one of these errors

My question is: Is there any Gem or tool (besides Intellij) to detect this kind of problems so I can add to my Rakefile and run it in my toolchain before my application gets deployed?

Comment: Here's a curated list of [Ruby static analysers](https://github.com/mre/awesome-static-analysis#ruby); for example, ruby-lint.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `debugger` anywhere before or after any code you would like to trace.
Once you do the action from the browser, your running server in shell will pause the work and give you the ability to trace your code and test it.

I would recommend you to read more about debugging Rails applications.
[Click here to read more about rails debugging](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)